# how to set sessionFactory instance only once for entire application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am Injecting sessionFactory Through xml file(applicationContext.xml) using this package org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.

is there anyway to set the sessionFactory only once for entire web application? how can I achieve this ?

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
         <list>
                    <value>com.mahesh</value>
            </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: 1. The title of the question and the question itself ask for different things. 2. Show us the bean definition in the XML (edit your question to do this!) 3. Why do you think that Spring creates more than one `SessionFactory` for the entire application?

Comment: Well, unless you use a non default scope (and you should **not**) for the sessionFactory bean, spring will use only one for the entire wep app ...

Comment: @AaronDigulla I pasted link which contains xml code snippet... I am confused how to access session in my all DaoImpl classes..... i am doing basic CRUD operations using getHibernateTemplate...am I missing something?

Comment: Show us a bit of the code in your DaoImpl class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you tell Spring otherwise, it will create each bean once per context (i.e. they will be singletons). Your XML will do just that, so it already does what you want.